# Issue with duplicate Manifest ID in Microsoft AppSource

Tags: office-addins, office-store

I received the validation error below in my seller dashboard validation test results:

`The Add-in Manifest ID used in your add-in's manifest appears to be a duplicate of a different add-in already submitted to Microsoft AppSource. This ID must be unique.`

This is likely due to me accidentally submitting a validation request to Teams App first. Could someone from the Microsoft validation team please help me remove the manifest id from the system so I could re-submit my app package for validation? Or please let me know how I should proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This failure is unrelated to submitting a review request to Teams via email. The manifest ID in the manifest uploaded to SellerDashboard must be unique. The validation team cannot delete manifest ID's for any app or add-in.

If you have previously submitted your add-in via SellerDashboard, then subsequently created a new listing you would encounter this issue. If this is the scenario, then either submit your app on the original listing, or else alter the manifest ID on the second listing.